# How to calculate population per cell in QGIS

Tags: qgis, population, flood

I am a beginning to QGIS and I am working on a project on the number of population affected by flood.

I have a vector layer of district boundary joined with the population census data (csv, no geometry).

I have rasterized the district boundary layer because I will be doing analysis by overlapping two raster layers (population_boundary layer and spreading_of_flood layer) and working on zonal statistics.

I want to calculate the population per cell in each district, I have tried using the zonal statistics but it doesn't give the right results. I have also thought of converting the district boundary to points with regards to population but I couldn't think of a proper method to do with it.

Comment: **You can't un-aggregate population data!** The density of people per square unit is never uniform... just think, if your census block has an open cut mine within, who is living there? Or apartment blocks dominate on one edge, there's no way to account for these differences.